# Comparing spatio-temporal variations across multiple years

Tags: geospatial, spatial

I am new to spatial statistics. I am working on a project analyzing the spatio-temporal neonatal mortality. I have data for six year from 2012 to 2017 specified at district level per month. 
How can I compare the spatial variation of neonatal mortality rate across the 6 years. I would want to be able to explain statistically the changes of the neonatal mortality rate either for each district or the country as a whole for the 6 year period.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far, and can you give an example of the type of data you are intending to manipulate.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Data is in a shapefile with the number of neonatal deaths and number of live births per year for the 6 year period together with the district names and unique district codes. I have computed the neonatal mortality rate for the period and a global moran's for each year. So what I have been trying to do is find a way to compare the spatial structure over the period to identify any statistically significant changes.